# Create a map with a particular type of data

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to set values in a particular format as follows:

`discoveryAttr[0]["add"] = []string{"brand_name"}`

How to design my map here?

Here 0 is not a slice index. It refers to the value of item - like itemId.

Comment: is discoveryAttr a map?

Comment: @matt.s Yes, it is a map.

Comment: It isn't obvious since you have an integer key, which could be an index instead.

Comment: @matt.s Yeah. I have updated the question to make it clear now.

Answer (score 2):

A go map must have 2 components only.

map[key]data -> key and data can be any type of value.

In the above case, the 1st key is int. Hence the value must mapstring

Hence, the type will be `map[int](map[string]([]string)))`

Comment: discoveryAttr could also be a slice containing maps, so []map[string][]string would also work, right?

Comment: @Prateek, the parentheses aren't necessary (though they can be helpful), so the type is more accurately `map[int]map[string][]string`.

Comment: @tsdtsdtsd It cannot be a slice. Slice cannot be accessed via key.

Comment: @matt.s Yes, the parenthesis are helpful for understanding although not required.

Comment: @Prateek yes, but the "0" can easily be a slice index rather than a key: https://play.golang.org/p/hcAAm3aF4G.  In that case, the same assignment syntax (`discoveryAttr[0]["add"] = []string{"brand_name"}`) could mean that `discoveryAttr` is a map of ints to maps of strings to slices of strings, or it could mean that `discoveryAttr` is a slice of maps of strings to slices of strings.  Both are valid interpretations.

Comment: @Kaedys Yeah, I cleared up the issue in Question Description now.

Comment: @Prateek ok, then the nested map version is the correct way of doing it.  `map[int]map[string][]string`.

Comment: @Kaedys Yes, I have mentioned the same in answer along with parenthesis to make it easy to understand.